# JavaFx update linechart which is part of fxml does not work

Tags: javafx

I am new to JavaFx:
In my FXML I defined a linechart and over a controller I want to change e.g. the title of the chart.

But somehow it is not working.

Here the FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ui.views.view2.viewView2Controller">
   <children>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
         <children>
            <Label text="View 2 Area" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#nextPane" text="view 1 page" />
            <LineChart fx:id="testChart">
              <xAxis>
                <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
              </xAxis>
              <yAxis>
                <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
              </yAxis>
            </LineChart>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Here the controller Code:

```
package com.ui.views.view2;

import com.ui.libs.VistaNavigator;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;

public class viewView2Controller {
    @FXML
    private LineChart<String,Number> testChart;

    @FXML
    private Axis<String> xAxis;

    @FXML
    private Axis<Number> yAxis;

    public viewView2Controller()
    {
        xAxis = new CategoryAxis(); // we are gonna plot against time
        yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Time/s");
        xAxis.setAnimated(false); // axis animations are removed
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");
        yAxis.setAnimated(false); // axis animations are removed

        //creating the line chart with two axis created above
        testChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
        testChart.setTitle("my first JavaFX Chart");
        testChart.setAnimated(false);
    }

    public void nextPane(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        VistaNavigator.loadVista(VistaNavigator.viewConfig);
    }
}
```

Whats wrong in my code and what do I need to change that I am able to change the chart title and afterwards with the new recommendation also able to populate values into it. :-)

BR
Dieter

Comment: You're recreating a new chart instead of using the one in your fxml file

Comment: if I comment out this line " testChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);" I am getting a Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException. So whats wrong?

Comment: Your controller should implement `Initializable`. `initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)` is the method you need to initialize your data in, not in the constructor.

Comment: please stick to java naming conventions